# Getting this error when Choose an SDK to target 4.0 or 4.3 error

Tags: android

Getting this error when Choose an SDK to target 4.0 or 4.3:
[2012-06-20 17:20:36 - Emulator] emulator: ERROR: no search paths found in this AVD's configuration.
[2012-06-20 17:20:36 - Emulator] Weird, the AVD's config.ini file is malformed. Try re-creating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to detect the preferences -->android  path of  SDK and Renew the path it will work OR instal 4.0 and 4.03 sdk again this may also solve your problem

i hope this may help your problem